# Where can I find the exception stack traces in OpenShift Tomcat Cartridge

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openshift, jhipster

So I deployed a WAR file containing my jHipster app (Angularjs+Spring boot) on openshift Tomcat 7 Cartridge. I can open reach my application with no problems (the front end) but once I try to login (interaction with the backend) i get an error.

Normally I check the exception stacktrace in the console of Eclipse IDE if I am debugging my application locally.

I checked the logs in `app-root/logs/jbossews.log` but I only see that my app is deployed logs. like :

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/57582f677628e108ba000096/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Jun 10, 2016 10:43:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/57582f677628e108ba000096/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 29,121 ms
Jun 10, 2016 10:43:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.28.129-8080"]
Jun 10, 2016 10:43:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 29501 ms
```

Not my application exceptions.

Is there any configuration that I should add to get my application exceptions in the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your configuration but there is a "OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR" environment variable in every Openshift gear and you can use that to write your log files to the designated log directory.

Example in your spring-boot application.yml file, you can add

```
logging:
  path: ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}
  file: myApplication.log
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into this next time I use openshift. My first experience with a PaaS didn't go well so I switched to Amazon AWS and everything was much easier to grasp. Thanks again.